# Make a div pop onclick like the fancybox jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

i need to popup a div like the jquery [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) with elastic effect i am using the below coding but it not works...

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="LoginAnchorLink">ClickME</a>
<div id="dialog" class="Popup" style="display:none;">
    content of the div have to be popup
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Popup {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 100px; 
    height:100px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#LoginAnchorLink").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").fancybox();
    });
});
```

Am I missing something or has something gone wrong?

Comment: #LoginAnchorLink isnt referenced in your HTML.

Comment: is it possible to achieve the popup effect in div with zoom effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After re-reading it, I decided to edit the post.
This should be more clear.

Don't forget to attach the css and the javascript files for fancybox.

Your login form

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <div id="logindiv" style="width:400px;height:100px;overflow: hidden;">
        You div with login data and input fields
    </div>
</div>
```

Login link

```
<a id="loginbutton" href="#logindiv" title="enter your login details here">Login Here</a>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#loginbutton").fancybox({
            'titleShow'     : true,
            'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your HTML should have to change like dis

```
<a href="#" id="LoginAnchorLink">ClickME</a>
<div style="display:none;">
<div id="dialog" class="Popup">
    content of the div have to be popup
</div>
</div>
```

make sure the path of jquery library and fancybox js files

Comment: if he still uses the same jQuery code as posted, these html changes don't make any difference. You should propose a working jQuery code too.